# Why I'm getting "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" error?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, web-deployment

this is the code:

```
class QuoteBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            quotes: Data,
            current: Data[0]
        }
    }

    setRandomQuote(){
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.quotes.length);
        this.setState({
            current: this.state.quotes[index]
        })
    }

    render(){
        return <div id="quote-box">
            <p id="text">
                {this.state.current.quote}
            </p>
            <h5 id="auther">
                {this.state.current.author}
            </h5>
            <button onClick={this.setRandomQuote} id="new-quote">New Quote</button>
            <a href="" id="tweet-quote">haha</a>
        </div>
    }
};
```

and am getting this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
setRandomQuote

src/Components/QuoteBox/quoteBox.js:15
  12 | }
  13 | 
  14 | setRandomQuote(){
> 15 |     const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.quotes.length);
     | ^  16 |     this.setState({
  17 |         current: this.state.quotes[index]
  18 |     })

View compiled
▶ 19 stack frames were collapsed.
```

why state is undefined when it has been initialized in the constructor, Im new to react so i would like to understand exactly what is happening and why. thanks.

Comment: When passing class methods as callbacks they need to bound to the component instance. See https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Comment: yeah it works now thanks but why i need to bind it manually? shouldn't stuff like that be already included in the framework? (behind the scenes) @azundo

Comment: How would react know that you want the function to be bound to `this`? If they did something like bind every function passed to an onClick prop, then 1) they'd cause unnecessary memory and cpu overhead and 2) Anyone who wanted to bind the function to something else would run into a bug.

Comment: i see, sounds logical, thanks for the explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to deal with this, the two most common approaches for class components are to bind the function to the component or to use an arrow function. Examples of both follow.

Function binding in the constructor:

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        quotes: Data,
        current: Data[0]
    }
    this.setRandomQuote = this.setRandomQuote.bind(this)
}
```

Using an arrow function: (thanks @Linda Paiste)

```
setRandomQuote = () => {
   const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.quotes.length);
   this.setState({
       current: this.state.quotes[index]
    })
}
```

However, if you're just getting started I would strongly encourage you to use functional components and be careful with any materials you read that use class based components, as they may be dated.

Below is your class, refactored to a functional component. Make sure you import {useState) from react.

```
const QuoteBox = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    quotes: Data,
    current: Data[0]
  })


  const setRandomQuote = () => {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * state.quotes.length);
    setState({
      ...state,
      current: state.quotes[index]
    })
  }


  return (<div id="quote-box">
    <p id="text">
      {state.current.quote}
    </p>
    <h5 id="auther">
      {state.current.author}
    </h5>
    <button onClick={setRandomQuote} id="new-quote">New Quote</button>
    <a href="" id="tweet-quote">haha</a>
  </div>
  )

};
```

Comment: yeah it works now, but why should i use functional components? is it better?

Comment: IMO, functions are better. Since hooks were introduced most of the React community has moved away from class based components in favor of functional components. In most cases they are easier, take less code and are more flexible.

Comment: classes are almost unnecessary so I agree with this answer.

Comment: useful link thanks man, i just wanted to practice the normal way to use a state, before i move to react hooks.

Comment: Cool, but hooks are the normal way now. :) Enjoy.

Comment: I would recommend a function component too, but you can avoid the need to `bind` by using an arrow function in the class.  `setRandomQuote = () => {`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Linda. That's actually the preferred way. I'm going to update the answer to include that as well.